# what is the default password for the `jupyter` user on AI platform notebook VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

i just tried to install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) on my notebook instance. it asked for the `jupyter` user's password, but i have no idea.

i'm also tagging with `gcp-ai-platform-notebook` as the [support page](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/getting-support#questions) says to do. thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: jupyter user password is no set. I would advise you to use `sudo -i` to login as root.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) using “**sudo -i**" to login as root. It’s installed successfully.  So, I would advise you to use “**sudo -i**” to login as root before installing [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh).

Comment: But sudo -i still requires a password

Comment: I'm in the same position. There are no clues I see to finding where the password is as everything is created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the password using the following

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

You will require `sudo` permissions. This can be done by adding **Compute Admin** role to the service account and restarting the VM

Comment: I tried this, but I still get asked `[sudo] password for jupyter:`. Is it different for a managed workbook in Vertex AI?